# Cisco ISE VM server and eapol_test(free radius) on same network through VPN

Tags: authentication, radius, cisco-ise

My cisco ISE server is on a remote VM and i have installed free radius tool eapol_test to test EAP-TLS authentication. When i send auth request to eapol_test tool, it times out at the client end and gives error message "11007 Could not locate Network Device or AAA Client" at ISE server end. I tried connected them throug VPN which brings ISE and eapol_test client on same network but to no relief.

Comment: Can the devices ping each other?

Comment: For the source IP of your eapol_test running system, did you add a "Network Device" record to the ISE?  See: _Administration -> Network Resources -> Network Devices_, with the appropriate details such as Type, IP address and most importantly _Shared Secret_ ?

Comment: ISE cannot ping the switch, although they exist on same network connected through vpn. Although switch can ping ISE server.

Comment: The network device is indeed added with correct settings.

Comment: Well, it still looks a lot like the ISE does get the request but for some reason does not want to answer. The ISE does give a hint with claiming that `11007 Could not locate Network Device or AAA Client`.  Does the log entry on the ISE have details about which IP address caused this error, and does that entry match the IP you are expecting?

Comment: Post the ISE record